# Deleting row (or array item) permanently - swift 3/4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After successfully deleting a row from `UITableView`, I go to another view controller but when I return to the `UITableView` the deleted row is back again. Am I missing something? I am relatively new to `Swift`.

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        self.queuelayout.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        print(self.queuelayout)
    }
    return [delete]
}
```

I've also tried with this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        queuelayout.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
    }
}
```

Look forward to your help.

Comment: Are you filling `queuelayout` elsewhere?

Comment: is `queuelayout` (should be `queueLayout` by Swift naming convention) your data model? Can you confirm that the entry really gets removed? It sound like not. Are you assigning your array to a different variable in your data model, like `guard let array = arrayOptional else { return [] }`. Remember arrays are value types, so doing that creates a copy of the array.

Comment: Thank you @Carpsen90 & DuncanC, for your responses and sorry  I had to travel for work but I am getting back on this now... I think E.Coms is right, I am calling the array at viewDidLoad : 'queuelayout = createArray()', then how do i work round this issue? how do you guys delete an item permanently from an array?

Comment: @DuncanC see note above.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your top codes. They are all right.  The only possible reason is as you said you went to another VC , you have already get rid of your tableViewController from the memory. Here is an simple example:
  [image]

If your tableView is the most right one, and when you go back to middle vc, your right one will be removed from the memory. Then when you click assign button and actually, you are loading a completely new tableViewController.

As a result, viewDidLoad will be called and your tableViewController will init again to the original states.

You may set a breakpoint at func viewDidLoad(), to check this situation. If this one is not called when you go back, you are good to go. Otherwise, everything will be reset. All what you delete will reappear as they should.

This is a simple example. Your case may be a little complicated. But if your tableviewcontroller called  ViewDidLoad(), you must have some hassles somewhere.

Hope this help you out.

Comment: Thanks @E.Coms, sorry for delayed reply, had to travel for work, I am getting back on this now.
You are right, I am calling the array at viewDidLoad : 'queuelayout = createArray()'... Then how do i work round this issue? how do you guys delete an item permanently from an array?

Comment: one way is to use a global var: queue layout and init in AppDelegate. Another is save the array to default after deleting. Then every time read it back from default propertylist.

Comment: Ok thanks E, I'll do some research on these options and their implementation. If you have resources / links on this, pls let me know. Thanks again buddy. I'll keep you posted.